# jQuery Submit Heisenbug

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a heisenbug - it works when I put a Firebug breakpoint on it, but it doesn't work without the breakpoint.

The LoginSubmit function is called from two places in my code. In one instance, the btnLoginSubmit_Click event is fired successfully, but in the other instance, the event doesn't fire unless I put a breakpoint on the $submitButton.click(); line.

```
function LoginSubmit() {
    $("#diagnostics").text("");
    var $submitButton = $("#<%=btnLoginSubmit.ClientID %>");
    $submitButton.click();  // <-- This is the line of code that is not executing.
    $("#diagnostics").text("LoginSubmit failed to submit postback. ");
}

  <asp:Button ID="btnLoginSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CssClass="hiddenButton" 
        OnClick="btnLoginSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="return true;" Visible="true" />
```

Code behind page:

```
   protected void btnLoginSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
....
    }
```

Comment: is the function called twice from the same button or two different buttons? If there's two different buttons, do they both have id ID="btnLoginSubmit"? Could that be an issue?

Comment: Are you calling LoginSubmit after the document is loaded i.e after/in document.ready?

Comment: Are both places that call the LoginSubmit_Click function caused by a user interaction? Or is the one that is failing called in another javascript perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Consider registering a PostBackEventHandler instead of firing the onclick of the button

```
  public partial class ScheduleEdit : System.Web.UI.Page,
        System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler
    {
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var postBack = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, null);

            var script = "function postback() { " + postBack + "; }";

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), this.UniqueID, script, true);
        }

        // this is called via the client side 'postback' script
        public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
        {
            DoStuff();
        }
    }


    // client side script:
    $("#DP").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) { postback(); },
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue involved a problem in jQuery involving dialogue boxes. When I closed the dialogue box before issuing the submit, it worked.